# Postgres SessionStore with many concurrent users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord, database-connection

I am using SessionStore to store my jruby Rails sessions in a postgres database. The connection pool configuration is:

```
pool: 10
timeout: 5000
```

In my testing, I found that with around 15 connections, I start getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds.  The max pool size is currently 10; consider increasing it.)
```

It seems like this is failing too early. Surely 10 DB connections can support more than 15 concurrent users? I am only using this database to access sessions, so I assume that each request only uses the connection for a small period of time. Are these failures happening at a reasonable time?

**How does Rails use DB connections for session store?** Does it hold the DB connection for the length of the request or does it simply load it once at beginning of each request? Any ideas about what could be causing this poor DB connection usage?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the session store that is failing to get a connection?  The settings apply to any connection made by the database, and presumably you're doing things in your app (other than session store) that require DB access.  I am quite sure you're right that the session lookup is very fast.  AFAIK, there's nothing special about PostgreSQL (that is, SessionStore is independent of database) and presumably is just a table lookup.

Comment: We only use the DB for sessions. The rest of our application does not require or use a database. Can you confirm that Rails does not _hold_ the DB connection for the life of the request?

Comment: Confirmed that SessionStore is about as simple as pie.  See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SessionStore including the comment.

Comment: Everything points to SessionStore being well behaved, and connection pooling doing the right thing (threading, queuing, releasing).  Are you certain your app is "warmed up" in your testing?  I have had cases where adding load causes my config (e.g. Apache/Passenger) to load more instances of the Rails stack, which, depending on the server can cause everything else to come to a grinding halt.

Comment: I only ever load one instance of the Rails stack, running on jruby with threads for concurrent requests.

Comment: Right (a good reason to run jruby).  Sorry, I am tapped out of ideas -- it *definitely* should be able to handle way more concurrent users.  I have run apps using DB Store that handle many hundreds of concurrent users (and also doing heavy DB stuff) -- it's got to be something else.  You may want to watch PG as it's running to see what's happening internally.  Or maybe put some instrumentation around the SessionStore stuff (e.g. `Rails.logger.debug "Opening connection at #{Time.now}"` in the gem code).